# how to filter number in python in 'def'

Tags: python

I am new to python.
I have set setting_data as below.
I want to filter pd_a, like I only want to select percentage above 25%.

```
 def setting_data(setting_df, _oil):
    try: pd_a = setting_df['PERCENT'].values
    except: pd_a = None
    try: pd_b = setting_df['RPM'].values
    except: pd_b = None
    try: pd_c = setting_df['pressure'].values
    except: pd_c = None
    try: pd_d = setting_df['temeperature'].values
    except: pd_d = None
    try: pd_f = setting_df['Engine Inlet Temp'].values
    except: pd_f = None
    try: pd_g = setting_df['T/C RPM'].values/1000
    except: pd_g = None
    try: pd_h = setting_df['BSEC'].values
    except: pd_h = None
    try: pd_i = setting_df['SFOC'].values
    except: pd_i = None
```

To select the percent above 25%, I have adjust code as below but somehow it returns value with 0.
Can someone please advise how to filter data to return values above 25%?

```
 def setting_data(setting_df, _oil):
    try: pd_a = setting_df['PERCENT'].values >= 25
    except: pd_a = None
```

Comment: if the type of `values` is a list, you need to do `[x for x in values if x >= 25]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 def setting_data(setting_df, _oil):
    try:
         pd_a = setting_df['PERCENT'].values
         if pd_a < 25:
             pd_a = None # Here you can set to the value which you would want if its less than 25
    except: pd_a = None
```

The problem with your code was that `setting_df['PERCENT'].values >= 25` does not filter the values but check if it it greater than 25 or not.

Comment: def setting_data(setting_df, _oil): try: pd_load = setting_df['PERCENT'].values if pd_a < 25: pd_a = 25 except: pd_a = None I have edited code as you suggested, but I got error message say 'x and y must be the same size'

Comment: please give some details

Comment: I have edited the code as you told, and with the setting_data I want to plot a scatter plot,I used if sensor_dic['rpm'] is not None: ax1.scatter(x=sensor_dic['PERCENT'], y=scaling(sensor_dic['rpm'], [ax_engspd[0], ax_engspd[-1]], range_list[0]), s=15, c='#8B4513'). When I run above code I get error message saying 's and y must be the same size'. Do you know what causes this problem?

Comment: most probably the length of the sensor_dic['PERCENT'] and scaling(sensor_dic['rpm'], [ax_engspd[0], ax_engspd[-1]], range_list[0]) list is not same and for plotting it must be same.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the operator `>=` is prioritized over `=`. The value of `pd_a` would be set as the returned value of operation `setting_df['PERCENT'].values >= 25`.

You could try this instead

```
def setting_data(setting_df, _oil):
    try: pd_a = setting_df['PERCENT'].values if setting_df['PERCENT'].values >= 25 else None
    except: pd_a = None
```

Comment: I have edited the code as you told, and with the setting_data I want to plot a scatter plot,I used    if sensor_dic['rpm'] is not None:
                       ax1.scatter(x=sensor_dic['PERCENT'],
                                          y=scaling(sensor_dic['rpm'], [ax_engspd[0], ax_engspd[-1]], range_list[0]), s=15, c='#8B4513'). When I run above code I get error message saying 's and y must be the same size'. Do you know what causes this problem?

Comment: Can you post the value of x and y? @H.Cho

Comment: @MinhVươngPhan x and y are the parameters sensor_dic['PERCENT'] and scaling(sensor_dic['rpm'], [ax_engspd[0], ax_engspd[-1]], range_list[0])